# Linking from UIViewcontroller to UITabBarController page

Tags: xcode, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a linking problem, am using xib's, not storyboard.

I have a UITabBarController system and a few other view controllers which sit away from the tab bar system. My question is can i link from a one of the view controllers using a button back to a certain page on the UITabBarController?

Answer (score 1):

The UITabBarController is the parent and the ViewControllers under the tabs are children. You can access the TabBarController from the childViewControllers by using the parentViewController property.

So, if you have a UITabBarController with 2 tabs which hold ViewController1 and ViewController2, you can use this line in either of them.

```
UITabBarController* tabBarController = (UITabBarController*)self.parentViewController;
// So if for example you have a button in ViewController2 and you need to show
// ViewController1 when it is pressed, you can do the following
tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
```

Comment: It would be better to just use the view controller's [`tabBarController` property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW31) instead of the `parentViewController` property.